# Count html tags with Perl regex

Tags: html, regex, perl, extract

I'm trying to parse an HTML file to count HTML tags. I'm not much familiar with Regexp though.

My current code counts only by line. not tag by tag. It returns the whole line.

```
while(<SUB>){
    while(/(<[^\/][a-z].*>)/gi){
        print $_;
        $count++;
    }
}
```

suppose that we have a line like this in the file

```
<div>blahblahblah</div><h1>hello</h1><p>blah</>
```

I need to extract the opening tag of every HTML tag and also tags like `<hr>`,`<br>` and `<img>`.

Could you please put me in the right direction.

Comment: consider using search engine to find alternatives to RegEx. I.e. Bing search http://www.bing.com/search?q=parse+html+perl+module may give you some links.

Comment: The selected answer to the above mentioned question says,
"Regex queries are not equipped to break down HTML into its meaningful parts."
is this totally correct?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov , thanks to you, perl Html::Parser is useful for me in this case. But I was learning RegEx. I thought this is an exercise to learn regex more. But seems I was wrong.

Comment: Read through high rated answers too - there are a lot of interesting things there. The third one (about grammars) gives you links that explain theory behind the restriction. Note that different languages/libraries often implement some extensions that may allow some parsing of nested structures.

Comment: @shan: Yes, it is totally correct. It is a bad choice to attempt processing HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: While it's true that you should never use regex to **parse** html I think they are not too bad a choice when you just want to count tags...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count HTML tags within a document I suggest that you use HTML::Treebuilder.

```
use strict;
use HTML::Tree;
use LWP::Simple;

my $ex = "http://www.google.com";

my $content = get($ex);

my $tree = HTML::Tree->new();

$tree->parse($content);

my @a_tags = $tree->look_down( '_tag' , 'div' );


my $size=@a_tags;
print $size;
```

Now you can specify different tag names instead of div and count all different tags that you require. I suggest studying HTML::Treebuilder as it is a very useful module and you may finds methods you may find useful.